# Access JSON from Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I would like to check the available disk space in an Ansible script. For this, I have started the following task:

```
- name: Test for available disk space
  setup: filter=ansible_mounts
  register: disk_free
- debug: var=disk_free.ansible_facts.ansible_mounts.size_available
```

The output says that the variable is not defined, but this seems to be the path. Any idea what it is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ansible_mounts* is a list because there can be multiple mountpoints on a system.

Try using disk_free.ansible_facts.ansible_mounts[0].size_available and see if it returns a value.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This returns the size available. Thank you.